# Filtering the import from DB2 Table into Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, db2

I have an Access database where I Link a DB2 Table . The name of this table is **VWD**. I made an append query to filter this Table in two fields. I want to know if there is a possibility to create a same filter to the table before linking using any VBA macro? I have seen some posts where it is possible to do it with VBA-Excel.

Is the same possible using MS-Access?

Here is the append query which I have to filter the two fields

```
INSERT INTO VWDRSSTA ( SYSTEM, EREIGNIS, DATUM_ZEIT, ANTRAGSNUMMER, VORGANGSNUMMER, VERS_NR_INT, DUNKEL, DOK_ART )
SELECT VWD.SYSTEM, VWD.EREIGNIS, VWD.DATUM_ZEIT, VWD.ANTRAGSNUMMER, VWD.VORGANGSNUMMER, VWD.VERS_NR_INT, IIf(VWD.EREIGNIS="POL_AN" And VWD.DUNKEL=1,1,0) AS DUNKEL, IIf(VWD.EREIGNIS="EIN-ES" And  VWD.DOK_ART="EN","EN","") AS DOK_ART
FROM VWD;
```

Although it works fine. I need to improve the performance, for which I think is a good solution to have the filter before linking.

Comment: You need to clean up your terminology or description of the problem. Are you 'importing' a table from DB2, or are you simply 'linking' to a table in DB2? If you are using VBA code to IMPORT from DB2 into Access, then yes, you can create a query with a filter and save the results into Access.  Please describe the issue and show any code you may have done for this.

Answer (score 0):

To filter "before" linking, create a view in DB2 with your filter, and then link the view.

Or create a pass-through query applying the filter and use this as source for a recordset. This, however, will be read-only in Access.